# How to test mat-paginator

Tags: angular

I have this mat-paginator:

```
<mat-paginator #paginator [length]="totalRecords" (page)="pageEvent = paginatorEvents($event)" [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions" [pageSize]="pageSize"></mat-paginator>
```

How can I get a reference of it's previous and next button in `.spec.ts`?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this in your component:

```
@ViewChild('paginator') paginator: MatPaginator;
```

In your test class:

```
component.paginator.nextPage();
```

This is from the doc: https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api